# Effective way to store a list of booleans in SQL

Tags: sql, sqlite, data-structures, boolean

I've got a limited list of booleans,
example:

```
 {true, true, true, false, false, true}
```

This list is part of a Object (there might be up to 100 of these objects) like(example):

```
 {INDEX, STRING, false, **{true, true, true, false, false, true}**, FUNC_A, FUNC_B, FUNC_C}
```

Due prevention of dataloss is highest priority, I save a copy of the Object in a SQLite3 Database.
But I am a totally beginner in SQL.

My question is, how can I save the booleans with little calculating affort but best security?
The program is running on a 200mhz MCU with only 16mb flash memory, thats why I want to minimize calculation affort, still security and size are more important.

My idea so far:
Converting the booleans to a bitfield and just insert it.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a limited list of booleans, just store them in the native boolean type in your database or as tiny integers.  Yes, these are 8-bits instead of 1-bit.  For such a small list, the additional overhead should be negligible.  Plus, you won't incur as much overhead in unpacking the bits when you want to use them.

I'm not sure what you mean by security, but databases offer lots of security options, particularly by restricting access to particular databases and tables.  How the data is stored is generally not a security issue, except for obvious things like encrypting credit card numbers and social security numbers.

Comment: I'm storing the objects in a Database to prevent loss if the powersupply is interrupted due any issue, thats the "security" issue I'm talking about. You're surely right about that point. The overhead is a topic due there might be about 100 objects and the MCU only got 16mb of flash memory and beside the software there are also some images to store. So every kb I can save is a gain. Sure, the images are a better(more effective) way to lower the needet memory, but that's another topic I am also aware of.

Comment: booleans are stored as integers and these are at least 1byte. That means 8 booleans are 64 bytes + 8 * overhead, as a bitfield with 8 values(bits) is only 1 byte + 1 * overhead. Maybe I misunderstood your answer, but this seems to be a lot saved space.

Comment: @Sempie . . . How booleans are stored depends entirely on the database, and you haven't specified the database.

Comment: See the tags, it's SQL.

Comment: @Sempie . . . SQL is a language used for accessing relational databases (and some non-relational data stores).  A standardized description of the language is provided by ANSI.  However, each database vendor/project implements their own system.

Comment: Uh seems like I misunderstood something, as I said, beginner to SQL and Databases at all. Checked it, it's SQLite3 which makes my question obsolete. SQLite3 has no boolean type if I got that right, but a 1byte Integer seems to be fine.